# How do I write a text file with certain format?

Tags: python, format, text-files

My initial data was this but i want to write this data such that it is formatted in
"cat_id|content" like the one below this

```
5 Name NRIC DOB 1932.11.26 Race Chinese Sex Female ND - PATIENT CARE RECORD  
4 Name NRIC DOB 1933.05.01 Race Chinese Sex Male PM - PATIENT CARE RECORD
```

I would like the desired format to be write in this format in text file:

```
cat_id|content
5|Name NRIC DOB 1932.11.26 Race Chinese Sex Female ND - PATIENT CARE RECORD  
4|Name NRIC DOB 1933.05.01 Race Chinese Sex Male PM - PATIENT CARE RECORD
```

i did this because large number of content in a forloop (just for your understanding)

```
text_file = open("ED_Notes.txt", 'w')
for item in arr_cat:
    text_file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

please do help thanks!! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Igle hi i have added the codes i have tried

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

**Demo:**

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    toWrite = ["|".join(line.split(" ", 1)) for line in infile]     #Iterate each line and split by first space and the join by |

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:          #Write back to file. 
    for line in toWrite:
        outfile.write(line)
```

**Output:**

```
5|Name NRIC DOB 1932.11.26 Race Chinese Sex Female ND - PATIENT CARE RECORD  
4|Name NRIC DOB 1933.05.01 Race Chinese Sex Male PM - PATIENT CARE RECORD
```

Comment: I also want to write cat_id|content into the textfile @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with regular expressions.

I would try something like this:

```
import re

text_file = open("ED_Notes.txt", 'w')

for item in arr_cat:
    m = re.search("([0-9]) ([a-zA-Z].*)",item)
    text_file.write(m.group(1)+"|"+m.group(2))
text_file.close()
```

I'm sorry I'm in hurry so I didn't test it